# Problems with free() function in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, strlen

I have a `while` loop inside a `for` loop to handle strings. Here is basically the structure of my code:

```
char myString[1000];
//Initialize and maybe change myString
for(/*conditions*/){
    while(/*conditions*/){
        if(strchr(myString,' ') == NULL){
            break;
        }
        char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(myString));
        strcpy(temp,myString);
        *strchr(temp,' ') = '\0';
        strcat(myString," ");
        strcat(myString,temp);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Sometimes, this code works just fine, but sometimes the process ends and returns 3 which means that there is an error (3 is the return value that I usually get when I try to use NULL where I shouldn't like for example `myPointer->example` where `myPointer` is NULL). After some tests, I found out that the line that was causing the problem is `free(temp);`. I tried to replace it with `if(temp != NULL){free(temp);}` but it didn't change anything. I tried to declare `temp` with `char temp[1000]` instead of `malloc` and take away the `free(temp);` line but it still does the same thing. If I take away the `free(temp);` line and still use `malloc` the problem is solved but instead there is a huge memory leak, so I can't do that. If there is an error or not depends on what is in the `myString` string, which means that if there is a certain value in there, there always is an error, and if there is another certain value, there never is an error, but I can't manage to find out what type of values work and which ones don't, it seems to be random.

Why does `free(temp);` sometimes work and sometimes not and how can I get it to always work?

Comment: `char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(myString));
        strcpy(temp,myString);` out-of-bounds write, undefined behavior. Also, undefined behavior for `NULL`-dereference if `strchr()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Also, `sizeof( char )` is one by definition, thus it's redundant as part of the argument passed to `malloc()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem was caused by a simple typo.

Answer (score 5):

The major problem is, you're allocating one element less than the required memory.

`strlen()` does not account for the terminating null, so you're one short of the required memory. Later, doing

```
strcpy(temp,myString);
```

is actually out of bound access (to store the terminating null) which  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). As a result, you get to see

> *Sometimes, this code works just fine, but sometimes the process ends and returns 3 which means that there is an error[....]*

To resolve, you should modify the allocation statement like

```
char *temp = malloc(strlen(myString) + 1); // +1 for terminating null,
                                           // sizeof(char) == 1, guaranteed by C standard.
```

<del>That said, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)</del>

> <del>The `strchr()` and `strrchr()` functions return a pointer to the matched character **or NULL if the character is not found.** [...]</del>

<del>and, for the highlighted scenario,</del>

> <del>`*strchr(temp,' ') = '\0';`</del>

<del>attempts to dereference a null-pointer constant (`NULL`) which is invalid and again, invokes UB. Check for a valid return value before dereferecing the returned pointer</del>

Comment: .... and in case of UB any expected or unexpected result can take place.

Comment: @haccks Right sir, just quoted the part from the question to make this relevant. :)

Comment: @DonaldDuck check the edit in the answer, if problem persists, please create a MCVE.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I already dealt with that in the beginning with `if(strchr(myString,' ') == NULL){break;}`. So `strchr(test,' ')` shouldn't be NULL since at that point test and myString are the same and if there isn't any space in myString it exits the while loop.

Comment: @DonaldDuck makes sense, striked that option out.

Comment: The problem was that I forgot the +1 for the terminating null in the malloc. You can delete the part that you crossed out.